# mongorestore Error: recv(): message len too large

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm trying to restore my local mongo data backup to a remote data server. My MongoDB shell version on the Google Cloud Compute server is 2.6.6, local MAC OS 10.10 shell version is 2.6.9. I couldn't find anything about this error in the official docs. Does anybody know what caused the message too large error?

```
recv(): message len 759714643 is invalid. Min 16 Max: 48000000
```